# How to implement some python functions with Azure Data Factory activity?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azureservicebus

Description scenario:
I have an Azure Service Bus and received data on a topic.
Also, I have an Azure function ( Service Bus Topic Trigger ) when received a message on Service Bus then this function runs some functions on this message. ( see the below code )

The steps of functions are (Details of this code)

1. Received a message and convert it to JSON
2. Check the received message is valid or not
3. Check again a condition about the received message
4. If the above condition is TRUE
5. Create an array from the value of a filed in the received message
6. Run feature extraction on the output of step 5
7. Run normalization on the output of step 6
8. Run classification on the output of step 7 and add labels into the received message
9. The output of step 8, insert to database

Now, I want to know how can I implement and run these functions (steps) with Data Factory Activities as a pipeline. ( or other guide and suggestion about this scenario)

My code is:

```
import logging
import json
import pickle
import statistics
import config
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import azure.functions as func


def main(message: func.ServiceBusMessage):

    connection_db = psycopg2.connect(
        f"host={config.database_url} dbname=developer user={config.database_username} password={config.database_password}")
    cursor_connection = connection_db.cursor()

    """
    this functions validate and filters data with the folloeing criteria:
    message_type==50
    logical_id=='BLOCK'
    """
    message_body = message.get_body().decode("utf-8")
    message_body = message_body.replace(";", ",")
    message_json = json.loads(message_body)
    print("Json Converted")
    if message_json['error'] == {} and message_json['MSG_TYPE_TAG'] != '':
        logging.info("Data is Valid")
    else:
        logging.info("Data Not Valid")

    if int(message_json['MSG_TYPE_TAG']) == 50 and message_json['GET_RIGIDSENSE_SENSOR_ACCELDATA_LOG_TAG']['logical_name'] == 'BLOCK':
        message_filtered = message_json

        """
        this functions makes one array from the recieved array data
        """

        def _create_one_array(message_filtered):
            acceleration_array_of_all = []
            temp_array = message_filtered['GET_RIGIDSENSE_SENSOR_ACCELDATA_LOG_TAG']['acceleration_array']
            for value in temp_array:
                acceleration_array_of_all.append(value)
            return acceleration_array_of_all

        """
        features extraction functions
        """

        def percent_above_mean(acceleration_array_list):
            percent_above_mean = 0
            mean = np.mean(acceleration_array_list)
            for i in acceleration_array_list:
                if i > mean:
                    percent_above_mean += 1
            return percent_above_mean/len(acceleration_array_list)

        def variation_from_mean(acceleration_array_list):
            variation_from_mean = 0
            mean = np.mean(acceleration_array_list)
            for value in acceleration_array_list:
                variation_from_mean = variation_from_mean+abs(value-mean)
            return variation_from_mean/len(acceleration_array_list)

        def _feature_extraction(acceleration_array):
            feature = dict()
            feature['mean'] = np.mean(acceleration_array)
            feature['max'] = max(acceleration_array)
            feature['min'] = min(acceleration_array)
            feature['std'] = np.std(acceleration_array)
            feature['median'] = statistics.median(acceleration_array)
            feature['L1'] = sum(list(map(abs, acceleration_array)))
            feature['MAD'] = pd.Series(acceleration_array).mad()
            feature['percent_above_mean'] = percent_above_mean(
                acceleration_array)
            feature['variation_from_mean'] = variation_from_mean(
                acceleration_array)
            features_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(feature, index=[0])
            return features_dataframe

        def _normalization(df):
            scaler = pickle.load(open('scaler.sav', 'rb'))
            scaler.transform(df)
            return df

        """
        classification function
        """

        def _classification_lable(normalized_features):
            classifier = pickle.load(
                open('ExtraTreesClassifier.sav', 'rb'))
            prediction = dict()
            label = classifier.predict(normalized_features).tolist()[0]
            if label == 0:
                prediction['label'] = 'Hard'
            else:
                prediction['label'] = 'Easy'
            probablity = classifier.predict_proba(normalized_features)
            prediction['probability'] = round(max(probablity[0]), 2)
            return prediction

        def _classification(normalized_features):
            label = _classification_lable(normalized_features)
            return label

        acceleration_array = _create_one_array(message_filtered)
        extracted_features = _feature_extraction(acceleration_array)
        normalized_features = _normalization(extracted_features)
        label = _classification(normalized_features)
        logging.info('functions done')

        """
        Insert to database
        """
        message_final = {**message_filtered, **
                         message_filtered['LOG_TAG']}
        del message_final['error']
        del message_final['LOG_TAG']
        del message_final['acceleration_array']

        message_final['label'] = []
        message_final['probability'] = []
        message_final['label'] = label['label']
        message_final['probability'] = label['probability']
        cursor_connection.execute(
            '''INSERT into dci_output_lable VALUES (%(MSG_TYPE_TAG)s , %(ATTACHED_DEVICE_SERIAL_NUMBER_TAG)s, %(date_time)s , %(name)s , %(number)s , %(sequence)s , %(label)s , %(probability)s);''', message_final)
        connection_db.commit()
        logging.info("Insert to database done")

    else:
        logging.info(" Input data isn't BLOCKS")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Azure Function` activity in Azure Data Factory to run your Azure Function.

1. Create Azure Function Linked service. Get the Function App URL and Function Key from your **Azure Function**.

[image]

[image]

*Linked service details*:

[image]

2. Create a pipeline in Azure data factory and add `Azure Function` activity to it.

   (i) In settings, specify the linked service created.

   (ii) Function name will be the name created for your Azure function.

   (iii) Method: Function method to call.

   (iv) Body: Request to function call.

[image]

3. You can see the output once the pipeline is executed successfully.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Reference: [Azure Function activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity)